# Quickfix on windows not working as expected?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, dll, quickfix

I am using "quickfix_net.dll" and "quickfix_net_messages.dll" downloaded from [quickfix.org](http://quickfix.org).

I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express and doing development in fully managed environment.

When I receive a message through `fromApp()` and call `crack()` on that message, then any `onMesssage()` is not called and on console it says:

> unsupported message type 'D' for NewOrderSingle.

However I have defined `onMessage()` for `QuickFix42::NewOrderSingle`. Also, I have debugged and found that the `QuickFix::Message^` reference obtained in `fromApp()` contains `NewOrderSingle^` reference.

Comment: I think there is just not enough information here to solve your problem.  Can I see the content of your `onMessage()` call?

Answer (score 0):

it seems very strange. I never had this problem. Please take a look a this answer:

[why FIX fields using quickfix are null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364570/why-fix-fields-using-quickfix-are-null/13365292#13365292)

and let me know.

Comment: Hi, any news about your problem?